# Converting float Point to decimal number Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, numbers, rounding

I have stored a value in decimal form 300.300

which is stored as 300.30000000000001 in Redis sorted set (According to redis docs)

I want 300.300 from that 300.30000000000001

Comment: If you want the computer to do that, then you have to remember the result of 1/3 to perfect precision as well. You can't, because our base-10 number system doesn't support it. Well, the computer's base-2 number system doesn't support 3/10.

Comment: it can be also 3000.3000 so what to do there